# "How was yours?" response

Tags: traducción, cortesía

Suppose someone asked you a question like "How was your lesson?" and you replied and then wanted to ask the same question in return ("How was yours?"). I understand you could repeat their question such as "¿Cómo fue tu clase?" or reply with "¿y tu?".

Is there a way to shorten this first one to just "how was yours?" if the context has already been established?

Answer (score 5):

"¿Y tu?" doesn't work well, since you are using 'tu', referring to you.

If you would like to ask for the class instead of the person, you would say  "¿y la tuya?". I'm afraid that there is not anyway to shorten any more than saying this if the context has been establish already.

---

By the way, it is not 'tu', but 'tú' (with an accent).
Example: 'tu casa, tu perro...', it always goes before a noun, but the pronoun is 'tuya'. 'Tú' refers to you (yourself).

Comment: There's no need of "Wrong!!!!" Too much exclamation marks. This is not a TV contest.

Comment: What's the rule for the gender of "tuya"? is it always feminine or does it depend on the gender of the person or the gender of the object being referred to?

Comment: @RobBarr "tuya" is a pronoun that acts as a placeholder for "clase", so it should have the same gender as the object it replaces.